# Регулярным выражением вырезать все option определенного select`a

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Допустим, есть

```
 <select id="select">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
     <option>5</option>
     <option>6</option>
</select>
```

Как регуляркой вырезать все option'ы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    s/<option.+?\/option>//g
```